# How to correctly model loosely-typed properties in RavenDB

Tags: persistence, ravendb, json.net

I am new to RavenDB and looking for guidance on the correct way to store loosely-typed data. I have a type with a list of key/value pairs. The type of the value property isn't known at design time.

```
public class DescriptiveValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I query a DescriptiveValue that was saved with a DateTime or Guid Value, the deserialized data type is string. Numeric values appear to retain their data types.

Is there an elegant solution to retain the data type or should I simply store all values as strings? If I go the string route, will this limit me when I later want to sort and filter this data (likely via indexes?)

I hoping this is a common problem that is easily solved and I'm just thinking about the problem incorrectly. Your help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**:
The output of this unit test is: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2/2/2012 10:00:01 AM (System.DateTime)>. Actual:<2012-02-02T10:00:01.9047999 (System.String)>.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Store_WithDateTime_IsPersistedCorrectly()
{
    AssertValueIsPersisted<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);
}

private void AssertValueIsPersisted<T>(T value)
{
    ObjectValuedAttribute expected = new ObjectValuedAttribute() { Value = value };
    using (var session = this.NewSession())
    {
        session.Store(expected);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }

    TestDataFactory.ResetRavenDbConnection();

    using (var session = this.NewSession())
    {
        ObjectValuedAttribute actual = session.Query<ObjectValuedAttribute>().Single();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Value, actual.Value);
    }
}
```

I would expect actual to be a DateTime value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that RavenDB server has no notion of the type of `Value`. When sending your object to the server, `Value` is persisted as a string, and when you later query that document, the deserializer does not know about the original type, so `Value` is deserialized as a string.

You can solve this by adding the original type information to  `ObjectValuedAttribute`:

```cs
public class ObjectValuedAttribute {
    private object _value;
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value {
        get {
            // convert the value back to the original type
            if (ValueType != null && _value.GetType() != ValueType) {
                _value = TypeDescriptor
                    .GetConverter(ValueType).ConvertFrom(_value);
            }

            return _value;
        }
        set { 
            _value = value;
            ValueType = value.GetType();
        }
    }
    public Type ValueType { get; private set; }
}
```

In the setter of `Value` we also store the type of it. Later, when getting back the value, we convert it back to its original type.

Following test passes:

```cs
public class CodeChef : LocalClientTest {
    public class ObjectValuedAttribute {
        private object _value;
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public object Value {
            get {
                // convert value back to the original type
                if (ValueType != null && _value.GetType() != ValueType) {
                    _value = TypeDescriptor
                        .GetConverter(ValueType).ConvertFrom(_value);
                }

                return _value;
            }
            set { 
                _value = value;
                ValueType = value.GetType();
            }
        }
        public Type ValueType { get; private set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Store_WithDateTime_IsPersistedCorrectly() {
        AssertValueIsPersisted(DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void AssertValueIsPersisted<T>(T value) {
        using (var store = NewDocumentStore()) {
            var expected = new ObjectValuedAttribute { Value = value };
            using (var session = store.OpenSession()) {
                session.Store(expected);
                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var session = store.OpenSession()) {
                var actual = session
                    .Query<ObjectValuedAttribute>()
                    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
                    .Single();

                Assert.Equal(expected.Value, actual.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely - that's one of the strength of schema-less document databases. See here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link. I've updated my question to clarify the problem that I'm having. The unit test fails because the depersisted value is a string when I expect it to be DateTime. Any idea how to make this unit test pass?